# Сортировка гаек и болтов

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка, поиск

Здравствуйте.

Есть три задачи, которые подразумевают одну большую:

1. Реализовать алгоритм быстрой сортировки **(сделал)**.
2. Реализовать рандомизированный алгоритм быстрой сортировки **(сделал)**.
3. С помощью метода быстрой сортировки решить следующую задачу.
   "**Гайки и болты**":
   Неорганизованный плотник имеет смешанный набор **N** гаек и **N** болтов. Цель состоит в том, чтобы найти соответствующие пары гаек и болтов. Каждая гайка соответствует точно одному болту, и каждый болт соответствует точно одной гайке. Соединяя гайку и болт между собой, плотник может узнать из них больше (однако он не может сравнивать непосредственно две гайки или два болта). 
   Разработайте алгоритм для этой задачи, который использует в среднем **N log(N)** сравнений.

Первые две я сделал, но с пониманием третей задачи у меня проблемы:

1. Изначально методу должен передаваться один массив, или два?
2. Метод должен сортировать или искать в двух массивах одинаковые значения (пары гайка-болт)?

Еще я был бы очень благодарен, если бы мне разжевали эту задачу, насколько это воможно.

Спасибо.

Comment: @qwesc: А что значит «узнать из них больше»?

Comment: Как у вас представлены гайки и болты? Если они в одном массиве и вы его передадите, то

> однако он не может сравнивать непосредственно две гайки или два болта

вы будете сравнивать 2 гайки и 2 болта.

В случае двух массивов их оба можно отсортировать и сопоставить элементы.

Comment: Все, что у меня есть — это текст задачи. Никаких объяснений, примеров или входных-выходных данных..

Comment: А вам ясно, что значит N log(N)?

Comment: Время работы алгоритма. n - длинна массива.

Comment: http://kartikkukreja.wordpress.com/2013/10/29/matching-nuts-and-bolts-problem/

Answer (score 1):

Решить поставленную задачу можно двумя способами:

1. Итеративное решение
2. Рекурсивное решение

Вот тут в подробностях описаны два способа решение вашего вопроса, смотри [тут](http://learnc.info/algorithms/quicksort.html).